# Navigation From ErrorWidget to other Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I Have set a custom ErrorWidget for my application :

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ErrorWidget.builder = getErrorWidget;
    return TabsView();
}
```

Anyways,I've added a `RaisedButton` inside My ErrorWidget to let the user Navigate to other widget when he press Retry:
[image]

I've tried to use Navigator but I think  ErrorWidget isn't like MaterialApp so I get an Error context Undefined :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:awesome_loader/awesome_loader.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'MyLocationView.dart';
List _tips = [
  ('Searching...'),
  ('Tips :Turn On Wifi'),
  ('Tips :Turn On GPS'),
];
int i = 0;


Widget getErrorWidget(FlutterErrorDetails error) {
  return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          AwesomeLoader(
            loaderType: AwesomeLoader.AwesomeLoader3,
            color: Colors.teal,
          ),
          Center(
            child: CarouselSlider(
              height: 60.0,
              viewportFraction: 1.0,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              autoPlay: true,
              autoPlayInterval: Duration( seconds: 3 ),
              autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration( milliseconds: 800 ),
              items: _tips.map( (i) {
                return Builder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return Container(
                        width: 140.0,
                        child: Text(
                          ' $i ',
                          style: TextStyle( fontSize: 16.0 ),
                        ) );
                  },
                );
              } ).toList( ),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child :RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Retry"),
                onPressed: (){
                  //Here my button
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>MyLocationView()));
                }),

          ),
        ],
      ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Your `RaisedButton` looks okay, probably the problem is with your `context`. Could you add the code surrounding the `RaisedButton`?

Comment: `ErrorWidget.builder` is not made for something as trivial as an API fail, and especially not made to be overriding inside `build`. `ErrorWidget.builder` is applied to _all_ widgets. 

`ErrorWidget.builder` is for critical errors, the kind where your app went awfully wrong. It should never be used purposefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ErrorWidget is dedicated for critical errors and not for other usage.